# Setting x-axis ticks at intervals pmf in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot the pmf for temperature data, but all the x axis labels are overlapping.

my pmf data looks like this:

```
8.4     0.001212
8.6     0.000808
8.8     0.000404
8.9     0.001212
9.0     0.001212
          ...
```

I created this Series from the df sensor_a with the following code

```
pmf_a = sensor_a['Temperature'].value_counts().sort_index() / len(sensor_a['Temperature'])
```

where temperature the temperature column in the df sensor_a is temperature in degrees

this is the code that I used to make the plots

```
fig , axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 5, figsize=(20,5))
plt.sca(axes[0])
pmf_a.plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.title('PMF of the Temperature of A')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(sensor_a.Temperature), max(sensor_a.Temperature)+1, 2.0))
```

but this results in a group of x labels on the right.

Does anybody recognize this problem and have a solution?

[resulting plot with x axis labels to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIZ0y.png)

Comment: It seems plt.xticks is doing somthing wrong. Check np.arrange(...). Or, can you provide minimal code to reproduce?

Comment: Hi @Louise! Could you please give us a little snipped of the data inside `pmf_a`? Also, it would be nice to see the kind of values you have in `sensor_a.Temperature`. I tried simulating something and I get this weird arrangement of the xticks when the xrange and the values I'm trying to plot are not really in the same scale (so they end up being occupying a very small portion of the axis).